# Unexpected token import in babel

Tags: npm, babeljs, eslint

I have issue below. when I run gulp server. I got error relate to import path in gulpfile.babel.js. Below is that file and kind of error
I try many way but the result not change. Anyone can help me?

[gulpfile.babel.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJUqZ.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiRy2.png)

Comment: Do you have a .babelrc file?

Comment: Please add the error details.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the `babel-preset-es2015` dependency not be installed and present. Try installing the `babel-preset-es2015` dependency first by means of the following:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Then, create a file named `.babelrc` in the root directory of your project and enable the `babel-preset-es2015` preset by editing the file as follows:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: now I got "error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/pisces". I have created ~/.babelrc like your instruction

Comment: Silly question but just to be sure - is `babel` installed?

`npm install babel --save-dev`

Comment: tou need to create the `.babelrc` file in the root of your PROJECT, not your home folder